# How to programmatically stimulate autosave of a Simulink model?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have other functions and scripts that will make un-undo-able (that's a different question) changes to my models, so I'd like to stimulate an autosave before those changes are made to act as an undo buffer of size 1.

The best I've come up with so far is to use the `model()` functional interface to stimulate an update. i.e. `model([],[],[],'sizes')` will stimulate an autosave, but it also creates a whole host of other work for my PC, and potentially leaves the model in a non-terminated state.

Comment: save the model and create a copy including the timestamp? Why do you need the autosave function instead of saving manually?

Comment: I don't want to overwrite the existing file on disc first of all.

Comment: Also `save_system(model, new_model)` will leave you with the new_model model name open instead of the original. Which would lead to a bunch of confusion or closing and re-opening nonsense.

Comment: Also using the autosave seems like a cleaner, faster, potentially more background way of doing this. It just also seems that they haven't exposed it through the API at all.